# What is the time complexity of setting a new vector equal to an existing vector?

Tags: c++, vector, time-complexity

Let's say we have a `vector<int> nums`, and we want to keep track of its original state, so we create a `vector<int> original` and set that equal to `nums` as follows:

```
vector<int>original = nums;
```

Would the time complexity of this be `O(N)` or `O(1)`?

Comment: it will copy each element, so it is O(N)

Comment: It is certainly not going to be O(1), since a copy of the data is being made. But since it is a vector of integers, the copy is likely to be optimized to copy larger amounts of memory at a time, so it will likely be better than, but not worse than, O(N).

Comment: @RemyLebeau — after the amount of data to be copied becomes significantly larger than the “larger amounts” that can be copied at a time any improvement from copying larger amounts becomes negligible. The time complexity is O(N). To put it more concretely, it takes twice as long to copy 20000 int values as it does to copy 10000, regardless of whether you’re copying one at a time or one hundred.

Answer (score 2):

**Every** value in the first vector `vector<int> nums`, must be individually copied into the second vector `vector<int> original`. So the time-complexity would be `O(n)`.